# Docker: Running dotnet publish -o /output results in a nonzero error on CLI

Tags: asp.net, docker, .net-core, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS,

---

```
Docker-compose v 1.18.0-rc2, build 189468b
Docker version 17.12.0-ce-rc1, build ee2f943
```

---

Running this command: ***dotnet publish -o /output*** with docker results in this error:

---

```
ERROR: Service 'generator' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c 
dotnet publish -c Release -o out' returned a non-zero code: 145
```

---

[image]

I've installed the .NET SDK for Ubuntu and not sure how to resolve this error; it just won't create that publish folder; here's dotnet --info

> joel@worker-2:~/workspace/asp (copy)/api$ dotnet --info .NET Command
>   Line Tools (2.0.2)
>
> Product Information:  Version:            2.0.2  Commit SHA-1 hash: 
>   a04b4bf512
>
> Runtime Environment:  OS Name:     ubuntu  OS Version:  16.04  OS
>   Platform: Linux  RID:         ubuntu.16.04-x64  Base Path:
>   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.0.2/
>
> Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host
>
> Version  : 2.0.0   Build    :
>   e8b8861ac7faf042c87a5c2f9f2d04c98b69f28d

[Link to the same question worded differently with more error logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981793/docker-compose-service-failed-to-build-the-command-bin-sh-c-dotnet-publish)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are seeing is because your project contains a `global.json` file that pins the required SDK version to 2.0.2. However, the docker images contain newer SDK versions (current one is 2.1.3) which. Because no 2.0.2 SDK is present in the docker image you use to build, it just errors out.

Comment: That seems more specific than my answer. I'll bet a +1 on this answer.

Comment: Oh interesting, thanks Martin, let me modify my global.json and run it again!

Comment: @Martin Oh wow that was it, it works now, thank you so much!!! Thanks to VonC as well, tremendously grateful to both of you! Quick question though, how did you find out about the newer 2.1.3? How could I find that out myself so I can maintain my scripts as newer SDK versions come out? What did you do to find that version 2.1.3 ?

Comment: Oh did you open the Dockerfile for the base image corresponding to the 2.0 tag of (FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2 AS build-env) and from that native dockerfile, saw that they were doing a pull from (FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0.4-sdk-2.1.3-stretch) ? Is that the process you used to determine which was the current SDK? I need to know this to be able to maintain our CI code base as these images switch from under our feet. Lastly, would you recommend saving these working SDK to our own private registry so we're protected against breaking changes like this or NO because we lose the updates?

Comment: I happen to follow .net core releases and this is similar to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/1150). Unless there will be some "minimum version" support in global.json I suggest updating it for every release so you don't accidentally build with outdated tooling or delete the file and keep your tooling up to date on all machines.

Comment: Thanks I'm new to .Net Core; so you're saying if I delete that global.json it won't throw all kinds of error right? It'll just always default to the latest release, is that correct?

Comment: Yes that’s correct. Just make sure to update your local installations regularly

Answer (score 1):

First, if you are using Ubuntu, docker for Windows is not relevant.

I see `dotnet publish -c Release -o out` used in "[Dockerize a .NET Core application](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/)" (and the repo [`dotnet/dotnet-docker-samples`](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker-samples)) with images starting with

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env
```

It is a tag which is multi-arch, meaning it will pull either Windows or Linux containers depending on the host (here Ubuntu)
But you mention in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47981793/6309) following the [pluralsight.com course `docker-images-containers-aspdotnet-core`](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/docker-images-containers-aspdotnet-core), and that one might only work when done on Windows (meaning Windows server 2016/2017, able to execute Windows images)

Comment: Thanks VonC, great intro to an answer. I agree, the multi-arch means that it will target Linux (Ubuntu in my case) or windows(which I don't care about right now). The pluralsight one is also multi-arch so I'm confused but I see that you don't seem 100% sure as well when you say it "might only work when done on Windows" - I'm still a newbie so trying to absorb as much as I can

Comment: @pelican yes, my point is that I am not sure that specific tutorial is able to run on Linux.

Comment: so it seems I cannot use my Ubuntu for my CI/CD pipeline since our apps are built on .NET standard and .NET Core right? I understand .NET Core is cross platform but as we saw earlier doesn't seem to run simple commands like dotnet publish on linux. It's frustrating because Ubuntu VMs are free and I can throw them away and recreate new ones but with Windows I need to purchase licenses for say Windows 10 Pro or Server 2016/2017. I'll try to follow their .NET core application tutorials for Linux but it seems that we can't use Docker on Linux for plain .NET apps, not Core ones

Comment: Could you please briefly explain the Docker for windows multi-arch again? My understanding was it would look up which host OS is running and based on that, pull the appropriate base image; so if I'm on Ubuntu, the lookup should force a Jessie or Stretch tag; instead what seems to happen is that this lookup is only performed if you're using Docker for windows which, I'm assuming, is different than Docker CE on Linux? Please what are you thoughts on this, I'm just trying to understand then I'll respond to your answer regarding the link u sent right above

Comment: @pelican On the multiarch part: see https://blog.docker.com/2017/11/multi-arch-all-the-things/ and http://container-solutions.com/multi-arch-docker-images/. If there is a version for Linux/Ubuntu, it should find it. But your tutorial might reference an image which is not compatible with Linux.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162049/discussion-between-pelican-and-vonc).